# Support DateTime and DateTimeOffset columns with the same model/context

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have a .NET 7 Blazor server-side application using Entity Framework 7 to access an external AzureSQL DB not maintained by myself which is also used by other apps.

Now the maintainer of the DB wants to change some columns from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` which breaks my EF-models.

Changing my models to `DateTimeOffset` easily solves that problem, BUT the live DB still uses the old columns - only the staging environment has the new columns so far.

As scheduling a synchronous update of the DB and all apps using the DB is not as easy, I was asking myself **if there is no way for EF to (temporarily) support both column types via some (optional) conversion?**

Comment: What about creating a new column, not changing datatype of the old one? And then removing the old one and renaming the new when all apps are updated.

Comment: @GuruStron and sync the two columns via some kind of trigger as they would need to contain the same data?

Comment: Yes, exactly, using temporary trigger.

Comment: Looking for exactly the same. I've been tinkering with value converters, but once you support DateTime in db and DateTimeOffset in efcore, updating datetime to datetimeoffset in db also breaks the EF-models in a running application. Will provide an answer if I get anywhere.